# ¿Cuánto espacio consume un import datapump?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo el log de un expdp y como saben indican el tamaño de cada objeto, por ejemplo:

```
. . exported "XXXXXX"."OBJETO1"             9.859 KB       0 rows
. . exported "YYYYYY"."OBJETO2"             8.484 KB       0 rows
```

Con un código sencillo puedes sumar todo el espacio que ocupa todos los objetos de un mismo esquema.

Este es mi código:

```
awk '
function human(x) {
         s=" B  KB MB GB TB EB PB YB ZB"
         while (x>=1024 && length(s)>1) 
               {x/=1024; s=substr(s,4)}
         s=substr(s,1,4)
         xf=(s==" B  ")?"%5d   ":"%8.2f"
         return sprintf( xf"%s", x, s)
      }
BEGIN{ 

 patron = ". . exported"
 a = 0


}
{

    if ( match( $0, patron ) )
    {
        if ( match( $6, "KB" ) )
        {
            size = $5 * 1024 
        }

        if ( match( $6, "MB" ) )
        {
            size = $5 * 1024 * 1024
        }

        if ( match( $6, "GB" ) )
        {
            size = $5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
        }        

        split ($4,objeto,".")
        gsub("\"","",objeto[1])

        #print (size " " objeto[1])

        array[objeto[1]] += size
        
        
    }
}
END{
    print("ESQUEMA: BYTES HUMAN")
    for (x in array)
    {
        #print x": " array[x]" "human(array[x])
        #print x": "human(array[x])
        printf("%s: %i %s\n", x, array[x], human(array[x]))
    }
    #print "fin"

}' ${1}
```

Con esta información preparé mi bbdd a cada esquema le di el espacio necesario que indicaba, a los tablespaces de indices le di un espacio aproximado, pero rápidamente me quedé sin espacio.

Creo que el problema viene por el tamaño de bloque de la base de datos, he intentado dividir el resultado en bytes por el numero de bytes por bloque y ni por asomo me da un tamaño aproximado al que obtuve en la importación de los datos.

¿Sabrían decirme cómo se puede calcular bien el tamaño?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No es la respuesta exacta a tu pregunta, pero: a) hay que ver si tienes campos LOB y cómo se representan ahí, pues normalmente escapan a esa medición de espacio b) efectivamente, en Oracle los bloques son por defecto de 8KB (a menos que los hayas cambiado), c) si asignas exactamente el espacio que te da tu cálculo, ¿qué pasa con el crecimiento esperado de esa BD?, d) hay que tener en cuenta lo que ocupan los índices.

Comment: Sí pero los indices van a otro tablespace, el tamaño del bloque efectivamente lo tengo en 8KB, y no hay ningún crecimiento, pues es una bbdd vacía a la que se le añade los datos de este expdp, si una tabla tiene lob en el expdp dirá exactamente lo que ocupe esa tabla.

Comment: En tu pregunta no es claro dónde te quedas sin espacio (esa frase sobre el tablespace de índices no es del todo clara) y la pregunta del crecimiento iba dirigida al crecimiento futuro de la BD, de si después de importar no va a recibir nada, nunca. Tienes algún mensaje de error que puedas incluir EN la pregunta, por favor?